# Windows Server 2012 erroneously complaining about domain functional level

Tags: windows-server-2012

I'm setting up a new Server 2012 Datacenter instance as a file server and I'm going through the warnings and errors found by Best Practices Analyzer. It is reporting only one error which, as far as I can see, is erroneous.

The error is "The domain functional level should be Windows Server 2003 R2 or higher when using an identity mapping solution". The solution it links to is nothing more than a document that provides instructions on raising the domain functional level. I have confirmed that my domain functional level is at Server 2008 and I only have two DCs (Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2) and one domain.

So before I exclude this result and move on with my life I'd like to know if anyone has any information on it.